# no matching function for call to stof

Tags: c++

Trying to take values in string saving it in vector and stop once 'q' is given as an input. Then copying the values in other vector of float type and printing its value.
But can't change string to float and it is showing error. I am using stof() to do so.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;
int main(){
    string addDigit;
    vector<string> values;
    vector<float> number;
    while (cin >> addDigit) {
        if (addDigit == 'q') {
            break;
        }
        else {
            values.push_back(addDigit);
        }
    }
    int size=values.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        float num=std::stof(values[i]);
        number.push_back(num);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
       std::cout<<number[i];
    }

    cout << "\n" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"But can't change string to float and it is showing error"* - And what's the error? Would you ask a doctor to diagnose you without telling them details about what what hurts?

Comment: `values` is a vector of characters. `values[i]` is a single character. `std::stof` expects a string. A string and a character are two very different things. A vector of characters is not a string either. If you need a string, spell it `std::string`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica that's on the top ''no matching function for call to stof"

Comment: We both know very well that's not the entire error message.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. After changing it is still showing the error of not able to call the function. Can you please change it and show it in code

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yes. Sorry. Here it is:
error: no matching function for call to 'stof(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type&)'

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. Converting a single digit to a floating point number doesn't seem reasonable to me.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I mistakenly wrote char instead of string. I was wanting to insert decimal numbers like 42.13 into a vector and was wanting to stop taking values when a character is entered. The only way I could find to stop vector taking values is by making the vector as string and then converting it back to float. Can you please suggest other ways for same. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a couple of things to fix your code, keep in mind the following:

- You are using `stof()` for your comparison, and stof converts a **S**tring**TOF**loat, so you won't be able to provide it with a char as you are doing right now
- It's better that you actually check if the input value is actually a number before trying to save that into your float vector

To solve the two problem above, you could actually just use the verification provided by `cin.good()`, which will also clean up the code quite a little. If the provided input can be stored into the float-type variable `number`, the `while` loop will add the number to the vector `numbers` and ask for another input. To quit the loop, just enter whatever cannot be stored into a `float`. Could be your letter "q" too!

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<float> numbers;
    float number;

    cin >> number;

    while (cin.good())
    {
        numbers.push_back(number);
        cin >> number;
    }

    for (auto i : numbers)
        cout << i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The stof function takes an std::string an converts it to a floating point number, but you gives a single char which can not be converted to an std::string.

There is another function atof which would nearer to what you expects, but it takes a pointer to an 0-terminated array of characters which you also not have.

To convert a single character to the corresponding decimal value, you can simply values[i]-'0', because the characters in the ASCII code are arranged in such a way that the letter '5', for example, is 5 positions from the letter '0' away.